# Accordian filter expanding and contracting all when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a product page that contains a sidebar of filters for the product. Each product contains a set of tags that are used to create the filters for that page. I am trying to put the filter groups into accordions which I have managed to do. However, when I click to expand or contract one of the group they all expand or contract.

I believe it is because I am setting each of the accordions to active when clicked. However I am struggling to set only the group I click to active.

The HTML Code below is looped for each filter group that the product have.

**HTML Code:**

```
  <h5><a href="#" class="tgl_btn">{{ cat_item }}</a></h5>
  <div class="tgl_c">
    <ul class="advanced-filters">   
      {% comment %}
      Loop through collection tags
      {% endcomment %}
      {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
      {% assign cat = tag | split: '_' | first %}              
      {% if cat != tag and cat_item == cat %}
      {% comment %}
      Strip out tag category prefix and add/remove link for tag filtering
      {% endcomment %}
      {% if current_tags contains tag %}
      <li class="advanced-filter active-filter" data-group="{{ cat_item }}" data-handle="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag | remove_first: cat_item | remove_first: '_' | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}</li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="advanced-filter" data-group="{{ cat_item }}" data-handle="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag | remove_first: cat_item | remove_first: '_' | link_to_add_tag: tag }}</li>
      {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**JS Code**

```
  $(".sidebar h5").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().find(".tgl_c").slideToggle(300);
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `$(this).parent().find(".tgl_c").slideToggle(300);` gets the parent then finds **all** `.tgl_c` and calls the `slideToggle()` method. Instead, try: `$(this).next().slideToggle(300);`.

Comment: Awesome that worked thank you. If you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().find(".tgl_c").slideToggle(300);
```

… gets the parent then finds all `.tgl_c` and calls the `slideToggle()` method. Instead, try:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle(300);
```